# Selecting items from ArrayList across beans

Tags: jsf, cart

I'm creating a webshop and I have it taking info from a SQL database and putting in into an array of items in a bean called `MySQLBean`. So far so good.

```
private void doSelect() {

    try {Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
       try {PreparedStatement dbQuery = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * from item");
            ResultSet resultset = dbQuery.executeQuery();
            results.clear();
            while(resultset.next()){
                results.add(new Item(resultset.getInt("id"),
                                     resultset.getString("name"),
                                     resultset.getDouble("price"),
                                     resultset.getString("description")));
            }
       }
       finally {conn.close();
       }
    } 
    catch (SQLException e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Now I have a button on the site which sends the ID from the item intended for purchase to another bean called `ShoppingCartBean`.

```
<h:form prependId="false">
    <h:commandLink id="addToCart"
        action="#{shoppingCartBean.addToCart(item.id)}"
        styleClass="btn btn-default">
        <i class ="icon-search"></i> #{msgs.addToCart} 
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

After having sent the `item.id` data to my `shoppingCartBean`, I wish to select the item with the corresponding `id` from the array I loaded earlier and add that entire item to a new array so that I can print the list of items to my user at a later time. But I'm completely stumped on how to do this.

EDIT: Formatted wrong
EDIT: Attempted to clarify question

Comment: How do you select the item ?! please post your `xhtml` code

Comment: Thanks for the interrest in my problem scorpion, im afraid i can see from your question that i didnt phrase mine very well.

The xhtml code above sends the item.id to the shoppingCartBean, it's there that i wish to take that info, look through my old item array, find the corrosponding item and add that to a new array that i can print at a later time. I hope this makes sense, ill try to edit my original post too

Comment: Ok. I will answer as much as i understood, you can add your database data to a list and display this list using `<h:dataTable>` or `<p:dataTable>` and show any columns as you need and add a column with a button that takes the current item "row" and add it to what you want using action attribute. I hope this what you want.It something like [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml)

Comment: This ended up being the solution to my issues. Thanks everyone, i'll try to get better at phrasing my questions right

    `public void addToCart(int id) {
                this.id = id;
               
                
                for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
                {
                    
                    if( i == id){
                    
                    cartItems.add(results.get(i));
                }`

Answer (score 0):

Just send the entire item `#{item}` instead of only its ID `#{item.id}`.

In other words, instead of

```
action="#{shoppingCartBean.addToCart(item.id)}"
```

do

```
action="#{shoppingCartBean.addToCart(item)}"
```

with

```
public void addToCart(Item item) {}
```